# Tailor the Publish feature in VisualStudio to use specific paths for individual files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to tailor the Publish feature of VisualStudio (I'm using VS 2008) so that different files go to different directories.  I'm developing a web application which is used within a CMS (Immediacy) and the folder structure of the solution is quite different from the target folder structure.

e.g. in my solution I have:

```
MySolution\MyWebPage.aspx
MySolution\bin\MyWebApplication.dll
```

which needs to get published to:

```
CMS\Admin\Addins\MyWebSite\MyWebPage.aspx
CMS\Admin\bin\MyWebApplication.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.